# Filter using a dropdown menu by only one field

Tags: angularjs, filter

I'm a beginner in AngularJs. I'm trying to filter data, using a dropdown menu, by only one field :

```
<select ng-model="annee"  ng-options="annee.titre for annee in annees track by annee.id">

</select>
<ul>

  <li ng-repeat="x in accueils | filter:annee" > 
    {{x.titre}}
    <div  ng-bind-html="x.description  | to_trusted"></div> 
    {{x.date}}
    {{x.cout}} $
    {{x.participants}} participants

  </li>
</ul>
```

In each x, there is a field "annee", i want to filter by this field.

For a working example : http://plnkr.co/edit/MbfrhdKfbTObybsQvxrR?p=preview

Now the problem is, when i select an option in the dropdown, i lose all the data, the filter is not working.

Can you please help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VRrZv8cABKZzFuOr9j2r?p=preview)

Things are going as in your select you are getting complete object selected:-

for example:-
 if you select '2015-2016' you will get {"titre":"2015-2016","id":3} in $scope.annee.

So, in filter you need to search for  filter:{annee:annee.id} that means look for the annee inside accueils having anneed.id(this is from model).

```
<li ng-repeat="x in accueils | filter:{annee:annee.id}" > 
    {{x.titre}}
    <div  ng-bind-html="x.description  | to_trusted"></div> 
    {{x.date}}
    {{x.cout}} $
    {{x.participants}} participants

  </li>
```